# Quote identifiers issue with Symfony2 and postgres

Tags: postgresql, symfony, quotes, quote

I have a problem with symfony2 and postgres. I have a database with tables and sequences in uppercase, that I cannot modify.

I have generated the entities (reverse engineering), quoting the identifiers, and when I trying to do any type of modification (php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force), it returns the error:

**[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  no existe la relación «base_id_se
  q»
  LINE 1: SELECT min_value, increment_by FROM BASE_id_seq**

The code of my Base Entity is:

```
namespace Slip\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Slip\ContactBundle\Entity\Criterion;
/**
 * Slip\CoreBundle\Entity\Base
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Slip\CoreBundle\Repository\BaseRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="""BASE""")
 */
class Base
{
    /**
     * @var bigint $id
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="""BASE_id_seq""", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @var string $name
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=1024, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;
```

..............

If I change the name of the sequences to lowercase all works, and the modifications are applied to the database, but I cannot do it in production enviroment

I don´t understand why if I do any modification in the database, in other tables that aren´t the BASE table appears this error.

Thanks for your collaboration.

Answer (score 1):

Offhand I'd say Symfony isn't quoting the identifiers in the SQL it's submitting to PostgreSQL. You can verify this by taking a SQL trace; see the docs for [log_statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/runtime-config-logging.html). As with any DBMS other than SQL Server, if you created the identifiers with quotes you must quote those identifiers in all subsequent SQL that references them.

I know nothing about Symfony, but it probably has an option to force use of quoted identifiers or at least allow you to force quotes into your identifier names manually.

If it doesn't, and you can't touch the PROD tables, you're in a pickle. It appears PostgreSQL has only limited support for [updateable views](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Updatable_views). You might be able to combine views and rules to accomplish what you're after, but it's likely to be ugly. Try the Symfony approach first.